# Why do I need to pass (req, res, next) to bodyParser in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I had originally been using bodyParser as so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

However, now I want to conditionally use bodyParser:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/hooks') {
        next();
    } else {
        bodyParser.json()(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

When I try to remove `(req, res, next)`, the parser does not work. That is,

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/hooks') {
        next();
    } else {
        bodyParser.json();
    }
});
```

does not work.

**Why do I need `(req, res, next)` after `bodyParser.json()`?**

Comment: to understand it, read it's source

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/37e37c9bb5b213dd9b9ff3151695111a16eb8ca4/lib/types/json.js#L98

Comment: it takes argument `.json(options)`  which usually we pass nothing and then it returns middleware called `jsonParser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/index.js#L108

```
function bodyParser (options) {
  var opts = {}

  // exclude type option
  if (options) {
    for (var prop in options) {
      if (prop !== 'type') {
        opts[prop] = options[prop]
      }
    }
  }

  var _urlencoded = exports.urlencoded(opts)
  var _json = exports.json(opts)

  return function bodyParser (req, res, next) {
    _json(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) return next(err)
      _urlencoded(req, res, next)
    })
  }
}
```

Body parser is a middleware that needs access to res, req and next.

It parses your request using req and in order to pass control to the next middleware, it needs access to the next function.

Here `app.use(bodyParser.json());` are passed (req, res, next) by default as

`bodyParser.json()` returns `return function bodyParser (req, res, next) { .. }`

so it becomes --> `app.use(function bodyParser (req, res, next) { .. });`

but in your case, you are creating a middleware by your self and you are responsible to pass the parameters to `bodyParser` so it can have access to the required arguments.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/hooks') {
        next();
    } else {
        bodyParser.json()(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

See how `app.use` works below

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L187-L242